# XCode: cannot change Navigation Bar tint via Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

i wan't to give a NavigationBar a certain tint, however i cannot find the setting in XCode. Is it still present? I saw a number of tutorials mentioning that possibility (i.e. http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/).

Where do i have to click to get this dialog? I tried the NavigationController, everywhere inside the NavigationController and the Navigation Items in the subcontrollers.

I know how to do it programmatically so that's not my question here.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In your storyboard, you'll need to click on the "Navigation Bar" object and then look at the object's attributes.

In Xcode, it'll look like this:

[image: Navigation Bar Tint in Storyboard]