# Dark grey Navigation bar in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationbar

I have a navigation bar in my storyboard and usually when you add a navigation controller to a view controller you get a nice cream navigation bar like this: [image]

Instead of this however, I get a weird dark grey colour like so:

[image]

My question is how can I get rid of this annoying grey in the nav bar **in the storyboard** not in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select Navigation Controller -> Navigation Bar -> Attributes Inspector -> pick color for background as you want
[image]

Here is the result (iPhone 5s's screenshot):
[image]

Comment: I want the cream bar not the opaque white one. I can't find a setting for that in that menu. Furthermore, why does the storyboard infer that I want the dark grey bar and not the cream bar?

Comment: Maybe the answer is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046831/xcode-cannot-change-navigation-bar-tint-via-storyboard

Comment: Updated answer. Please check.

Comment: I checked but whatever colour I set it to, it doesn't change

Comment: That setting is in Navigation Controller, not in ViewController. Did you follow the introduction correctly? I tried and got the color changed.

Comment: I found the setting but what I did was turn translucency off and set the tint colour