# How to change UINavigationBar Title and Back Button Colour from Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode

What is the best way of changing colors for Title and Back button of UINavigationBar from Storyboard?

Comment: I hope this link could help you , https://stackoverflow.com/a/51062388/2323806
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21046988/2323806

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way of changing colors for Title and Back button of UINavigationBar from Storyboard?

The color of the title is an attribute of the navigation bar, so select the navigation controller's navigation bar:

[image: navigation bar selection]

and then look at the Attributes Inspector, where you can set the title color:

[image: title color]

The color of the Back button is controlled by the tint color. You can set the global tint color in the File Inspector for the storyboard:

[image: global tint color]

These settings should work fine if you want to set the title and tint color once for the whole app, but if you want different colors for different view controllers, then one way or another you're going to have to write some code. If that's something you need to do often, and you want to be able to set the colors in IB, you could consider writing your own `UIViewController` subclass from which all your view controllers are derived. Give that common controller class [inspectable](https://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/) attributes for the colors you want to set, and of course add code that sets them appropriately. You'll probably want to use [`UIAppearance`](https://nshipster.com/uiappearance/) for that.

Bear in mind, though, that the reason that these colors aren't already attributes of `UIViewController` is that the colors are supposed to help give your app a consistent appearance; changing your app's color scheme from one scene won't be a favor to your users.

Answer (score -3):

you can do it by code

```
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red


    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

    let button1 = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "search.png"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(barBut)) // action:#selector(Class.MethodName) for swift 3

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = button1

    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
```